# ASP.NET Web API and MonoDroid

Tags: xamarin.android, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a ASP.NET Web API that I have hosted in IIS from MonoDroid.  The service is fine and I can call it from different endpoints.  The problem is that in MonoDroid I get invalid cast exception when I try to do this.

```
var s = response.GetResponseStream();
var j = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load(s);
```

System.InvalidCastException: comes back on the load part.

I have done some reading and people seem to say to try to switch the Web API to use JsonNetFormatter class.  I tried that and still no luck.

Anybody have any ideas on what I can try?

## UPDATE

Here is payload

```
<ArrayOfAlbum xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; 
              xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">; 
   <Album> 
      <AlbumPK>f09d14cf-3bab-44c8-b614-2b7cf728efd4</AlbumPK>
      <Name>Colorado</Name> 
      <UserName>firstUser</UserName> 
      <ParentAlbumFK xsi:nil="true" /> 
      <DateCreated>2012-03-12T19:47:54.493</DateCreated> 
   </Album> 
</ArrayOfAlbum>
```

And

```
 [{"AlbumPK":"f09d14cf-3bab-44c8-b614-2b7cf728efd4","Name":"Colorado",
    "UserName":"emorin","ParentAlbumFK":null,
    "DateCr‌​eated":"2012-03-12T19:47:54.493"}]
```

Response from Fiddler changing the accept header to JSON.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 17 Apr 2012 19:45:47 GMT

97
[{ "AlbumPK":"f09d14cf-3bab-44c8-614-2b7cf728efd4","Name":"Colorado",
   "UserName":"emorin","ParentAlbumFK":null,
   "DateCreated":"2012-03-12T19:47:54.493"}]
0
```

Comment: Try calling the service from browser/fiddler/... and get the JSON and post it here. Without first looking into JSON do not change anything in your service.

Comment: Some more from Fiddler.HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 17 Apr 2012 16:20:56 GMT
Content-Length: 151

[{"AlbumPK":"f09d14cf-3bab-44c8-b614-2b7cf728efd4","Name":"Colorado","UserName":"emorin","ParentAlbumFK":null,"DateCreated":"2012-03-12T19:47:54.493"}]

Comment: So what is the first XML? which one is correct? Update the question please, do not use comment.

Comment: Sorry the first one was the XML from the browser.  The second one is what I am seeing in fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server is sending data in the chunked encoding and perhaps the MonoDroid is having problem understanding chunked encoding. Try turning it off in IIS.

Comment: In my mono app I am setting the header to json.  I will try it in fiddler.

Comment: I looked into turning it off, but my hosting company has no option for that.  The interesting thing is I tried deploying it locally and same result from fiddler about being chunked.  Even out of cassini I get the same thing.  Looking around the web I found a post saying that Web Api does not set the content-length so my guess is this causes the chuncked.